# Sencha Touch Cards Layout not working

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm learning `Sencha Touch2` and trying do a simple application to see how it works.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=2da#fiddle/2da

Comment: I remove from app.js and updated. This is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

0.- In your Fiddle you are using ExtJs as your Framework instead of Sencha Touch.

1.- You were trying to use  `'bolao.view.Main'` when it was never declared.

2.- `Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();` Is having trouble inside Fiddle but not when used       normally in your server.

3.- Even with this changes I can't manage to see it in Chrome, but I do see it in FireFox.

4.- Try this code in your Fiddle and then deploy it to your Apache or whatever server you are using.

5.- Don't use Fiddle for learning purposes (though it is cool for showing code).

6.- I recommend you to follow this tutorial http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/first_app

Code:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'bolao',

    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox'
    ],

    views: [
        'Main'
    ],

    icon: {
        '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
        '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
        '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
        '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
    },

    isIconPrecomposed: true,

    startupImage: {
        '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
        '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
        '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
        '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
        '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
        '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
    },

    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        //Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();  this line is having problems in Fiddle I think 'cos in my local server does work fine

        // Initialize the main view
        //Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('bolao.view.Main')); this view ('bolao.view.Main') is never defined
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel'));
    },

    onUpdated: function() {
        Ext.Msg.confirm(
            "Application Update",
            "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
            function(buttonId) {
                if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Best regards @code4jhon